# Table with fixed tbody height

Tags: html, css

I am having issue trying to make table 1 look like table 2 using css. I also noticed the increased height and watermark image does not reflect on print preview

Table 1
[image]

Table 2
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a row at the end of the tbody solve this.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S/N</th>
      <th>Description of goods</th>
      <th>QTY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Arch</td>
      <td>7.92</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>White</td>
      <td>3.96</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
td {
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

table {
  height: 150px;
}
tr:last-child {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Check my example https://jsfiddle.net/moisesnandres/4py2m8aq/